# Changing the python version of libboost

Tags: apt, boost

On Ubuntu 14.04, I believe I have installed libboost through

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends libboost-all-dev
```

In my /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu I have the files

```
libboost_python-py34
libboost_python-py27
```

As they are the default python installations found on the system. However, I wish to have the python3.5 version (which I have installed). How should I proceed?

Comment: AFAIK it will install (via a `libboost-python-dev` dependency) versions corresponding to the *default* python2 and python3 packages on your system - if you have manually installed a different version of python3 then you will likely need to manually install the corresponding boost bindings as well

Comment: Could you hint me how I should go about doing so? Does it mean that I have to compile boost?